# Does still make sense to use HOC with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question:

Does still make sense to use HOC with React Hooks?

If yes, in which cases would be a good idea to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Same type of questions comes with state/side effects managers libraries (redux-saga). I feel there is some confusion, sometimes react developers tell hook/context shall replace most things, sometimes they say they have no intent to do so... Interested by the answer too!

Comment: A HOC is just a function that takes a component and returns a component right? To me that makes even more sense with Hooks, HOC is a functional programming pattern (if we agree functional programming really has patterns) right, which is what these hooks are in the direction of. I think HOC will be of use in the same situations for hooks as with 'normal' classe based react.

Comment: I find it much more convenient to simply make custom hooks...

Comment: check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676762/3439101

Answer (score 11):

According to the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-replace-render-props-and-higher-order-components), only if the HOC needs to do more than to render a single child:

> #### Do Hooks replace render props and higher-order components?
>
> Often, render props and higher-order components render only a single child. We think Hooks are a simpler way to serve this use case. There is still a place for both patterns (for example, a virtual scroller component might have a `renderItem` prop, or a visual container component might have its own DOM structure). But in most cases, Hooks will be sufficient and can help reduce nesting in your tree.

As I interpret this, react-redux [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) would still be a valid HOC, though [`useSelector` and `useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) are available so why bother ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: React-Redux now [supplies their own hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), `useSelector` and `useDispatch`