# what's the different between render props pattern and custom hook pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

here's render props pattern

```
export const flip = () => ({
  flipResults: Math.random(),
});

export const CoinFlipLogic = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(flip());
  const handleClick = () => setState(flip());

  return children({
    rerun: handleClick,
    isHeads: state.flipResults < 0.5,
  });
};

export const CoinFlip = ({ showLabels, showButton }) => {
  return (
    <CoinFlipLogic>
      {({ rerun, isHeads }) => (
        <>
          {showButton && <button onClick={rerun}>Reflip</button>}

          {isHeads ? (
            <div>
              Head
              {showLabels && <span>Heads</span>}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              Tails
              {showLabels && <span>Tails</span>}
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </CoinFlipLogic>
  );
};
```

and here is custom hook pattern

```
export const useCoinFlipLogic = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(flip());
  const handleClick = () => setState(flip());

  return {
    rerun: handleClick,
    isHeads: state.flipResults < 0.5,
  };
};

export const CoinFlip = ({ showLabels, showButton }) => {
  const { rerun, isHeads } = useCoinFlipLogic();
  return (
    <>
      {showButton && <button onClick={rerun}>Reflip</button>}
      {isHeads ? (
        <div>
          Head
          {showLabels && <span>Heads</span>}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          Tails
          {showLabels && <span>Tails</span>}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

IMO, I prefer custom hook since I think it's more readable.

my question is:

what's the main different between those two design patterns and
how should I choose which one to use when it comes to design my react component,
and which pattern is used more in real world?

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387613/when-and-how-to-choose-between-react-hooks-and-old-hoc-props-passing

Comment: hey mandy, thank you for providing the link! it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Render Props pattern and the Custom Hook pattern are two different approaches for sharing logic between components in React. Both patterns have their strengths and can be used in different situations. Let's explore the main differences and how to choose between them:

1. **Render Props Pattern**:

   - In the Render Props pattern, a component receives a function as a child (typically named `children`) and calls that function to render content.
   - It allows you to encapsulate and share UI logic, and it's especially useful when you want to pass data and behavior to multiple child components.
   - It can make your component more flexible as it allows for dynamic rendering and composition.
   - The pattern is helpful when you want to share logic that directly influences the structure and appearance of the component's rendered output.
   - It's a good choice when you need to encapsulate complex or conditional UI rendering logic.
2. **Custom Hook Pattern**:

   - In the Custom Hook pattern, you encapsulate and share state and logic in a reusable function that returns the necessary values and functions.
   - It promotes cleaner and more reusable code by separating logic from the component's rendering.
   - Custom Hooks are great for encapsulating logic that doesn't directly affect the structure of the component but is more concerned with data or side effects.
   - This pattern is suitable when you want to share logic that can be reused across different components and doesn't rely on a specific rendering structure.

**How to Choose**:

- Choose the Render Props pattern when you need to share rendering logic and want more control over the structure of your components. If you have complex conditional rendering or need to pass data and behavior to multiple child components, this pattern is a good fit.
- Choose the Custom Hook pattern when you want to share state management and logic that can be reused across multiple components. If your logic is more about managing data or side effects and doesn't directly influence the rendering, this pattern is a good choice.

**Usage in the Real World**:
Both patterns are widely used in the React ecosystem, and the choice often depends on the specific use case and personal/team preferences. The popularity of one pattern over the other may vary from project to project.

- Render Props are commonly used in libraries and frameworks, and they are particularly handy for building highly reusable components.
- Custom Hooks have gained popularity in recent years because they promote cleaner, more modular code. They are often used in application-specific logic and state management.

Ultimately, the choice between these patterns depends on your project's requirements and your team's coding style. It's also possible to combine these patterns in more complex scenarios, using the strengths of both to create a flexible and maintainable codebase.